# Deleted question in meta?

Tags: discussion

A question was recently (<48° ago?) asked on Biology Meta by Masi, regarding research-type questions. I was the only user to answer. The question appears to have been deleted. I haven't seen this done on other SE meta sites, even when the questions and answers were far more contentious. Was it deleted by a mod?

As a new user here, I am concerned that I am responsible for it's deletion. Was there something amiss in my answer? Did I break some kind of site etiquette?

This is not an attempt to defend myself. I'm looking for honest feedback about this site's etiquette. I won't argue with answers (I hate that). I'm just confused. I tried asking in private but was instructed to post a question in meta (et viola!)

Thanks.

Comment: Users can delete their own questions, both on meta and regular sites. I (and other higher-rep users) can see Masi's question of a couple of days ago, since I hadn't refreshed the main meta page and the link was still there. I can post you a screenshot if you're interested, or would like a copy of the conversation in the comments for posterity.

Comment: @MattDMo - Thanks for the reply. :-)  So it was the OP who deleted the question? It helps to know I didn't break any site rules. I'm fine with it, don't need a copy, but thank you for offering.

Comment: This seems to be another example of the problem I'm describing in this Meta post: [Why are all traces of deleted questions removed?](http://meta.biology.stackexchange.com/questions/693/why-are-all-traces-of-deleted-questions-removed).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question was self-deleted by the author. This is possible in this case because there was no upvoted answer, the only answer had a score of zero.

Moderators can undelete such posts, but I don't think this would be particularly useful in this case.

Comment: Thanks. Not a problem. I've just never seen it done before. Glad for the explanation.

Answer (score 1):

I feel there's a latent polemic developing around @Masi 's questions, as can be noted from the recent downvotes/closed questions he's getting, and the extended discussions in comments trying to make sense of it all. Masi seems of good intention and holds a repectable amount of rep points. However, it is quite difficult to interact with pure speculation and poorly formulated elements unsupported by research litterature (in questions as in answers) without affecting the site's functioning, given this site's vocation to transmit scientific knowledge and thought.

So now what?

Comment: Try to help him with the comments to get his questions more clear. It is not necessary a reason to downvote him (in my opinion) since he is participating in the process and willing to improve and work on his questions.